# What are the causes of RejctedExecutionException?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Are there any other causes for RejectedExecutionException being thrown besides `shutdown()` being called  previously on the Executor (I'm using a singleThreadExecutor)? I have some crash reports as below. They are very rare and I can't reproduce on my devices. My code is too complex to post, but I'm not seeing how it's logically possible that any tasks are being submitted after `shutdown()` is called.

Are there any other reasons that RejectedExecutionException could be thrown here?

> java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@4194a5f0 rejected from
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@41a36e90[Terminated, pool size
>   = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 9813] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1979)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:786)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1307)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:81)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.submit(Executors.java:562)
>   at
>   com.smp.soundtouchandroid.AACFileAudioSink.write(AACFileAudioSink.java:28)
>   at
>   com.smp.soundtouchandroid.SoundStreamRunnable.processChunk(SoundStreamRunnable.java:469)
>   at
>   com.smp.soundtouchandroid.SoundStreamRunnable.processFile(SoundStreamRunnable.java:406)
>   at
>   com.smp.soundtouchandroid.SoundStreamRunnable.run(SoundStreamRunnable.java:223)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Your ThreadPoolExecutor is shutdown, or

ThreadPoolExecutor has a finite number of threads, or work queue has finite capacity and is full (e.g., LinkedBlockingQueue of finite capacity passed in to ThreadPoolExecutor constructor).